# Does LuaCrypto run on Windows?

Tags: cryptography, lua, sha1

I need to run LuaCrypto on win platform. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are mixed answers to this online; some people say they have gotten it to work, but I can't.  However, [Jeffrey Friedl](http://regex.info/blog/) (who has some understandable but point-missing and viciously-expressed gripes with Lua) has written up [SHA-1 in pure Lua](http://regex.info/blog/lua/sha1), which should run anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

I just pushed CMakeLists.txt to [my luacrypto fork](http://github.com/mkottman/luacrypto). That means if you have:

- [CMake 2.8](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html)
- [OpenSSL dev. files + binaries](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)

you should be able to compile it on Windows (tested on MinGW).